# "PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter" With Hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, hibernate-mapping

In the past I've used a java.util.Calendar with Hibernate 3 (from J-boss 5.1) and @Temporal annotation. After moving to Hibernate 4 (j-boss 7.1) I've run into this PropertyAccessException when trying a UserType instead.

My UT is really just a wrapper around org.hibernate.type.StringType since I'm just forcing the Calendar into a String and back to cope with relative time-stamps: SQL Timestamp Without Time Zone.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of [my-class]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:313) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
...
```

Any ideas how I can fix this exception?

EDIT: For the time being I've worked around it by dropping the UserType in favor of making the time-stamp a String, parsing, and formatting it within the setters and getters. I'd prefer to use the UserType or some cleaner solution if anyone knows of any.

Comment: This exception doesn't say much (other than it can't set the property). What does your entity look like?

Comment: Entity has a Calendar annotated with a custom class extending Hibernate's UserType. Sorry I can't say more. Time permitting I'll try to whip up an isolated, Hello-World example.